# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de una página web generado por un javascript usando XPath con Python?

Tags: python, xpath

Estoy tratando de copiar el valor generado diariamente por una página financiera utilizando este código:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
url = 'http://www.set-fx.com'
page = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
print(tree.xpath('//*[@id="trmPrice"]')[0].get('content'))
```

El cual sigue las recomendaciones dadas en [este sitio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51231743/getting-text-value-using-xpath-with-python). 
Pero el resultado que obtengo es `None`.  ¿Qué puede estar faltándole al código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es lo mismo lo que ves en el navegador web mediante el menú "inspeccionar página", que lo que recibe el navegador al hacer la petición HTTP, y que puedes ver si eliges en el navegador "ver código fuente de la página".

Esta segunda opción es la que te da el HTML que el servidor envió al navegador, y que coincide con la que puedes obtener con python y con el módulo `requests`. Y si miras en ese HTML buscando la cadena `"trmPrice"`, verás que aparece en un `span` como este:

```html
<span id="trmPrice"  style="padding-right: 2px"></span>
```

El cual como puede verse está vacío.

¿Cómo aparece en él la información que buscas? Pues debido a que esa misma página contiene un código JavaScript que rellena ese `span` con los datos que ha obtenido de una petición ajax. Más adelante en el mismo HTML encontramos:

```javascript
update = function() {
    new Ajax.Request("http://www.set-fx.com/stats?" + new Date().format('isoTime') ,
      {
        method:'get',
        onSuccess: function(transport){

          var response = transport.responseText;

          var data = response.evalJSON();

        //var data = transport.headerJSON;

          $('trmPrice').innerHTML = '<span>' + (data.trm==undefined?'':data.trm) + '</span>';
```

...etc...

Lo que ves en el navegador cuando haces "inspeccionar elemento" es *el resultado* de haber ejecutado el JavaScript de la página. De hecho, esta vista es cambiante pues siempre se está ejecutando javascript en respuesta a otros eventos, que pueden seguir modificando el documento.

Hacer *scraping* de una página así es difícil. No puede hacerse sólo con Python, sino que es necesario un *navegador web real* y completo, que reciba la página y ejecute lo necesario. Gracias a Selenium puedes usar python como "control remoto" para un navegador, simulando acciones del usuario y pudiendo acceder a datos del documento ya procesado.

Por suerte en este caso la cosa es mucho más simple, ya que podemos ver en la función javascript que antes he mostrado, que la llamada ajax se hace a la URL `http://www.set-fx.com/stats` pasándole en la *query* la fecha deseada. Es más, si no le pasas fecha también funciona.

El resultado de esa llamada AJAX es un JSON que contiene ya la información que necesitas, sin necesidad de usar Xpath u otras técnicas de scraping:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.set-fx.com/stats")
data = r.json()
```

El resultado `data` es un diccionario python con esta pinta:

```
{'avgAmmount': '665.639,00',
 'avgPrice': '3.284,49',
 'avgPriceChange': 'up',
 'closePrice': '3.287,45',
 'exchangeBuyPrice': '0,00',
 'exchangeSellPrice': '0,00',
 'formattedAvgPrice': '3,284.49',
 'formattedPrice': '3,287.45',
 'latestAmmount': '250.000,00',
 'maxAmmount': '10.000.000,00',
 'maxPrice': '3.291,00',
 'maxPriceChange': 'down',
 'minAmmount': '50.000,00',
 'minPrice': '3.279,10',
 'minPriceChange': 'up',
 'openPrice': '3.290,00',
 'openPriceChange': 'down',
 'price': 3287.45,
 'priceChange': 'up',
 'streetBuyPrice': '0,00',
 'streetSellPrice': '0,00',
 'totalAmmount': '64.567.000,00',
 'transactions': 97,
 'trm': '3.285,34',
 'trmPriceChange': 'up'}
```

En el campo `data["trm"]` tienes la información que buscabas.